# Javascript .toLocaleString() not honoring '2-digit'

Tags: javascript, datetime

*Original Question*:
How do I get the hour/month to respect a '2-digit' formatting.

```
const event = new Date(2012, 3, 20, 3, 0, 0);
```

Edit...
*Apologies all, I don't use this very often*

The real issue is depending on which version of chrome you are on, it respects this formatting differently:

For example:

```
new Date(1561984526000).toLocaleString("ja-JP", {hour: "2-digit"})
// Chrome 80 (and other releases): "08時"
// Chrome 79: "8時"
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to get correct output of hour: “2-digit” for toLocaleString(“en-US”) with AM/PM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988030/how-to-get-correct-output-of-hour-2-digit-for-tolocalestringen-us-with-am)

Comment: Maybe consider another method of testing your date formatting? MDN has a [section for `toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) on reasons to avoid comparing formatted date values to static values with this method.

Comment: Hi, in your edit you destroyed your original question.  Please restore the question so it makes sense in entirety.  (You can append.)  Thanks.

Comment: Also, now you seem to be asking the opposite - why it wasn't doing 2-digit before and now it is? Probably a bug that was fixed.

Answer (score 6):

this is because you forget to add **hour12**:false

```js
const myDate = new Date(2012, 3, 20, 3, 0, 0)
  ,   dateOpt = { month: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', hour12:false }
  
  
console.log( myDate.toLocaleString(dateOpt) ); // 20/04/2012 à 03:00:00
// or 
console.log( myDate.toLocaleString('en-US',dateOpt) ); // 04, 03
```

Comment: It's kind of stupid that you can't have padded 12 hour formats. "01:00 pm" apparently isn't valid. Makes input masking a bit more difficult.

Comment: @pbarney  not really `hour12:true` will add `AM` or `PM`

Comment: I think you're not understanding. You can have `1:30 PM` but _not_ `01:30 PM`.

Comment: @pbarney Ah, I see, your reasoning rests on a false base: the W3C imposes to respect the international standards of formatting of the dates / times according to each country, it is not made to format the dates and the times according to your fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I never trust in toLocaleString function, I prefer to use `getMonth` and `lpad` to formatting a date manually.

Another advantage is that you don't depend on anything to do it

```
function lpad (strModify, intMaxPad) 
{
    if (typeof strModify == 'undefined') 
    {
        return false;
    }
    strModify = strModify.toString();
    return strModify.length < intMaxPad ? lpad("0" + strModify, intMaxPad) : strModify;
}

$(function(){

    var objDate = new Date(2012, 3, 20, 3, 0, 0);
    console.log( lpad((objDate.getMonth() + 1), 2) + '/' + lpad(objDate.getDate(), 2) + '/' + objDate.getFullYear()  );
});
```

You can also use the <del>Moment</del> [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) library

Comment: This eliminates the locale awareness that `toLocaleString` offers - for example, m/d/y vs d/m/y formats for the date portion.  Also, the Moment team recommends [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) for all new development.

Comment: Yeah yeah, Luxon instead. But toLocaleString, has had constant changes through the browser versions, that has made some functions have unexpected behaviors. I think it is better option to use a library if you want to manage dates in javascript in the easiest way.

Comment: Sure.  Also, [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) and [js-Joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/) are good alternatives. :)