# How do I use .toLocaleTimeString() without displaying AM/PM?

Tags: javascript, time

How can I display a digital clock with the format "HH:MM" in Javascript?

The code below displays the digital clock in the format of "HH:MM AM/PM".

main.js

```
const d = new Date();
const cFormat = d.toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
    });
```

Edit: Although the code below works, I'd like to know if there is a way to do this via ".toLocaleTimeString()".

```js
const d = new Date();
const cFormat = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour: "2-digit",minute: "2-digit"});
cFormat.replace("AM", "").replace("PM", "");

console.log( 'cFormat -> ', cFormat )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript .toLocaleString() not honoring '2-digit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230961/javascript-tolocalestring-not-honoring-2-digit)

Comment: your code doesn't display in in the format of "HH:MM AM/PM". in my country.

Comment: Are you trying to display military time, or do you want to display AM/PM time just without the AM/PM?

Comment: @isaacsan123 I'm just trying to display it with the 12-hour format that excludes the AM/PM. I posted my answer, although I'm still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way

```js
const HH_MM = {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }

let cFormat = new Date()
               .toLocaleTimeString('en-US', HH_MM)
               .replace(/AM|PM/,'') 

console.log( 'cFormat -> ', cFormat )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const d = new Date();
const cFormat = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour: "2-digit",minute: "2-digit", hour12: true});
cFormat.replace("AM", "").replace("PM", "");

console.log( 'cFormat -> ', cFormat )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` function doesn't work in place, meaning it doesn't affect the original string.  It just returns a new string, so even in the answer you're giving, you still get AM.  You can tweak it like this:

```js
const d = new Date();
const cFormat = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour: "2-digit",minute: "2-digit"}).replace(/AM|PM/g, "").trim();

console.log(cFormat)
```

I understand that you want to find a different way other than replacing AM/PM with an empty string, but at this point, it doesn't seem like there's a way to do so other than using military time.

Answer (score 0):

```
let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace("AM", "").replace("PM", "");
console.log(time);
//expected output
//8:03:30
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit later, but you can do it using spanish format ('es-ES') and setting hour and minute as '2-digit'.

```
const dat = new Date();
dat.toLocaleString('es-ES', {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
```